# How to query inside JSON using TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript

I need to access objects and values inside a JSON using TypeScript.

I did some research and found this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query

Are there any other similar, more powerful libraries available?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash or underscore library for the json manipulation which will work perfectly in typescript

- lodash [link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)
- underscore [link](http://underscorejs.org/)

There are also 3/4 native ES6 object functions available in typescript which will help you here in case you don't want to use any 3rd party library.

- map
- reduce
- filter
- forEach

Comment: this is a nice description! I normally use map but these only works on array and mostly the list of data came in forms of array

Comment: i will modify my answer to make it more relevant